# How to display file list with inverted comma using command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to display file list covered with inverted comma with a comma using Command Prompt. Suppose my folder has few files like

```
abc.txt
hello.mp3
world.mp4
```

I want to run a script on command prompt which can store file name in a text file like this

```
'abc.txt',
'hello.mp3',
'world.mp4',
```

I tried some option with **dir** command but didn't work.

Comment: `for %a in (*) do @echo '%~nxa'`

Comment: Run the command on command prompt instead of powershell

Comment: The name of the `'` character is apostrophe. [In computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Computing), it's often called as single quote.

Comment: Thanks this works on cmd.exe, I was trying in powershell. Great Thanks @Stephan

Comment: yes yes, I will keep this in mind @vonPryz

Comment: As a side note, single quotes [are allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) in NTFS, so `Sean O'Malley.jpg` is totally legal a filename. If you have such files, parsing single quote separated data might be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

[edit - thanks to Compo for pointing out the missing "trailing comma".]

the following code will generate a list of file names wrapped in single quotes [also known as "apostrophe"].

what it does ...

- grabs all the file names in the target dir
- uses the `-f` string format operator to build the desired string
- sends the string to the `$QuotedFileNameList` var
- displays that collection on screen

you can save the list to a file with `Set-Content`. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$QuotedFileNameList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        "'{0}'," -f $_.Name
        }

$QuotedFileNameList
```

output for me, today ...

```
'.ses',
'ALSysIO64.sys',
'FXSTIFFDebugLogFile.txt',
'MpCmdRun.log',
'MTShell.m3u8',
'qtsingleapp-fmlast-93b-1-lockfile',
'~DF76B4F7376F975558.TMP',
```

Comment: the `output to text file` idea is covered by the `Set-Content` idea. ///// i entirely missed the trailing comma ... i will add that right now ... thanks for pointing it out! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Above works on `Windows Powershell`. Here's a new method if you have  `Powershell`

```
PS> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\
| Join-String -SingleQuote -sep ",`n" -os ','
```

or splatting

```
PS> $splat = @{ sep = ",`n"; os = ',' }

PS> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\
| Join-String @splat
```

output

```
'C:\Windows\addins',
'C:\Windows\appcompat',
'C:\Windows\apppatch',
'C:\Windows\AppReadiness',
'C:\Windows\assembly',
'C:\Windows\bcastdvr',
'C:\Windows\Boot',
'C:\Windows\Branding',
'C:\Windows\CbsTemp',
'C:\Windows\Containers',
'C:\Windows\CSC',
'C:\Windows\Cursors',
'C:\Windows\debug',
'C:\Windows\diagnostics',
```